# Why cocoapods is always reinstalled?

Tags: cocoapods

When you init a project it installs cocoapods. Then when you init another project, it installs again. Why its install cocoapod again?

Comment: "while cocoapod already exists in MAC-Intel" Can you explain that? Did you already installed it? How? and what asks you to install it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your projects cleanly separate from one another, every project gets its own set of supporting ruby gems, as dictated by its bundler. That, indeed, is the whole *point* of the bundler architecture; otherwise your gems would all go into the same central ruby library, stomping on and infecting one another.

Well, cocoapods is a ruby gem. So, like every other gem for the project, it gets its own copy for this project.

(And in any case you really shouldn't worry about this. The cocoapods gem is very small.)

Comment: Although from the console log I see that it first installs cocoapods and then the bundler. So I am not sure that cocoapods is installed thru bundler

Comment: That is irrelevant. React sets this up itself rather than just relying on the bundler. But the _architecture_ is still bundler architecture, as I said.